# Not loading web content with WKWebView

Tags: swift, uiwebview, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

in my app I have migrated from UIWebView to WKWebView. Everything works perfectly but I have a problem with one icon.

This is the icon displayed by UIWebView:

[image]

And this is the icon displayed by WKWebView:

[image]

The Web site displayed in my webView is optimized for mobile device but
the implementation of the site is not my work. My question is:
Why there is this difference from UI to WK?

It is because I have to set some settings in WK or this problem depends on the implementation of the web site?

Comment: you can use safari's develop menu to inspect the html in the webview and see what the problem is, have a look and see what it has for the icon in the code. if you are using the navigation delegate of the WKWebView make sure  you are not blocking the loading of the icon

Comment: The icon is a file .png as the other icons. I use the NavigationDelegate but I don't know as it is blocking the loading of the icon

Comment: all icons in web site's HTML is declared so:
<button id="search" onclick="myFunction()"> Search </button>

Comment: what defines the images that are loaded? you must have a CSS class or image that tells the browser to display the search icon?

Comment: The protocol of web site is "http".

Comment: I have solved the problem changing the prefix of url from "http" to "https". I don't know why but it works

Comment: arbitray loads setting most likely... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http